# Make a View draw synchronously

Tags: android

I want to call ScrollView#scrollTo after updating an EditText with `setText()`. The EditText does not draw before the scroll which throws things off. I found one workaround by putting the scroll statement into a `Runnable` and calling `view.post()`. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view.post()` perfectly fits your usecase. You want to execute code as soon as drawing is finished. This is exactly what this method is for.

Comment: does it make any difference which view you call with?

Comment: As for execution time: no, use any (active) view. The message queue is global in the thread. As for code readability: use a related view, e.g. the `TextView`.